# pentadactyl - Mapping <Leader><Esc>

Tags: firefox, pentadactyl

Is there anyway that we do this mapping in pentadactyl :

```
map <Leader><Esc> :<C-z><Esc><cr>
```

I've tried but it doesn't work. Thanks  :)

P/S: I knnow that it's not possible to send the `<Esc>` to browser but I don't know if we can send a combination of it.

Comment: please avoid these kind of questions . They dont provide positive discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was my typo problem

Wrong:

```
map <Leader><Esc> :<C-z><Esc><cr>
```

Right:

```
map <Leader><Esc> <C-z><Esc><cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

That must be possible, as some users configuration shows:

- https://github.com/yukihr/dotfiles/blob/master/.pentadactylrc
- https://github.com/yangchenyun/pentadactyl/blob/master/pentadactylrc
- https://github.com/Huluk/dotfiles/blob/master/pentadactylrc

You can inspire you from their configurations.

The problem in your case is that you must use `map`, `nmap`, `cmap` and so one (regarding what mode you want to edit) to map keys. `set` is to define values, options. Not keys.

Comment: sorry, I typed it wrong. In those configuration, they only map from other keys which don't combine with `<Esc>` to `<Esc>`